# Having Trouble with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

As of this date, what is the name of the oldest person? Include his or her age, person name, phone number, and title. NOTE: Just display the name of the oldest person.

I have been trying to answer this question using SQL Server and I am not understanding it.

This is the code I have right now:

```
Use AdventureWorks2014
Go

SELECT 
    p.FirstName, LastName, Title
    Employee_1, JobTitle, BirthDate
FROM 
    Person.Person AS p
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee AS Employee_1 ON p.BusinessEntityID = Employee_1.BusinessEntityID 
WHERE
    Employee_1 BirthDate * (SELECT % BirthDate AS [age] 
                            FROM HumanResources.Employee))
```

Comment: So what is the problem you face?

Comment: Provide the table for us if you could. Also,with some data is better.

Comment: `Where Employee_1 BirthDate * (SELECT % BirthDate` is nowhere near valid syntax. Do you know how to write a `select` statement? Do you know about `order by`? How about `top 1`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `*` does, but in SQL Server it's the multiplication operator, and I have no idea what your intent is with `SELECT % BirthDate` - I suspect you're looking for `MAX()`.

Comment: Please post your problem in clear terms with some sample output.

Comment: Are you downvoting the answers? I find nothing wrong with @Harsh's answer

Answer (score 2):

What is the earliest birthdate?

```
SELECT MIN(BirthDate) FROM Person.Person
```

Who has this birthdate?

```
SELECT p.FirstName, LastName, Title
   Employee_1, JobTitle, BirthDate
FROM Person.Person AS p 
WHERE P.birthdate = (SELECT MIN(BirthDate) FROM Person.Person)
```

What is their age, in years?

```
SELECT p.FirstName, LastName, Title
   Employee_1, JobTitle, BirthDate,
   DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Person.Person AS p 
WHERE P.birthdate = (SELECT MIN(BirthDate) FROM Person.Person)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple TOP query should work for you:

```
SELECT top 1 p.FirstName, LastName, Title
   Employee_1, JobTitle, BirthDate
FROM Person.Person AS p
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS Employee_1
ON p.BusinessEntityID = Employee_1.BusinessEntityID 
ORDER BY BirthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

In AdventureWorks2014 there are two tables that have birthdays... so find the oldest of both of them

```
 SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, LastName 
 FROM (
   SELECT FirstName, LastName, BirthDate
   FROM ProspectiveBuyer

   UNION ALL

   SELECT FirstName, LastName, BirthDate
   FROM DimEmployee
) AS all_people
ORDER BY BirthDate ASC
```